# to_json exception 'undefined method `[]=' for #<JSON::Ext::Generator::State:0x108823cd8>'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm using Rails 2.2.2, and when I require 'json', all my [object].to_json code returns an exception:

undefined method `[]=' for #< JSON::Ext::Generator::State:0x108823cd8>

When I use 'json/pure', I get

undefined method `only' for #< JSON::Pure::Generator::State:0x1072e11e0>

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Finally resolved it by using another JSON parser - yajl-ruby.  Would still love to know why json gem did not work if anyone knows.

Answer (score 0):

Try using another JSON gem yajl-ruby.  That resolved my issue.